# How to view HTTP Response message in Apache

Tags: apache, http, cygwin, response, logging

I just installed apache (1.3.33) via cygwin running on Windows XP. I have the server running (httpd) and when I direct a browser to http://localhost, it correctly pulls up /var/www/htdocs/index.html.en

I used the following command to look at the HTTP Request the client sent to the server, and the HTTP Response the server sent back to the client:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache/access_log
```

However, this only shows the HTTP Request information. Can anyone help me figure out how to view the HTTP Response message?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to just check the requests/responses in a browser (Chrome/FF)?

Comment: Only that I'd like to learn where to look this information up in the web server log files, possibly to resolve issues other users are having sending/receiving messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you out. It works well for me.

http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/show-headers-in-get-request.html